# Android: How to handle SSL error?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am new to android..i have created an app(service not an activity) which send user location to server..and it runs in background so that the app is hidden from user...i have used async task(doInBackground and onPostExecute method)...in coding i have used Thread.sleep(300000) for interval of 5 minutes but i want this app should run on start-up for this i have used BroadCast Receiver..but it is not running..

CheckinTask: `SSL error, attempting time correction:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificates`

this is service:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       

        Log.d("prakaash", "helllllooo");
        while(done) 
        {
            Log.i("hiiiii","hellllo");
            getLocation();
            gpsTraking();
            passing();
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.d("YASARKHAN", "ABHISHEKRAI");
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("distrroy","destry");

    }

    public void gpsTraking() {

        // check if GPS enabled
        if (true) {
            stAdd = "";
            double latitude = getLatitude();
            double longitude = getLongitude();
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            try
            {
                List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);
                Address a = list.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i <= a.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    stAdd = stAdd + "\n " + a.getAddressLine(i);
                }
                stAdd = stAdd + " " + a.getLocality() + "\n"
                        + a.getFeatureName();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // \n is for new line
            CharSequence d = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                    new Date());
            currentTime = d.toString();
            Log.d("currentTime", currentTime);

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            // get IMEI
            imei = tm.getDeviceId();
            // get SimSerialNumber
            simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        }


    }


    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * launch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    class SendFeedback extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... paramArrayOfParams) 
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("strIMEINumber", paramArrayOfParams[0]);
            request.addProperty("strSIMNumber", paramArrayOfParams[1]);     
            request.addProperty("strAddress", paramArrayOfParams[2]);
            request.addProperty("strTime", paramArrayOfParams[3]);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

            try 
            {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                // SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                String resultData = response.toString();
                Log.d("response", resultData);
                return resultData;              
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.d("My Error", "" + e.getMessage());

            }
            return resultData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            Log.d("mayuuuur","mayureshh");
            Log.d("strResult", result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
 03-15 11:37:39.761: D/AndroidRuntime(284): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-15 11:37:39.761: D/AndroidRuntime(284): CheckJNI is ON
03-15 11:37:39.881: D/AndroidRuntime(284): --- registering native functions ---
03-15 11:37:40.402: I/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=290 uid=10027 gids={1015, 2001}
03-15 11:37:40.702: D/dalvikvm(290): GC_EXPLICIT freed 788 objects / 56280 bytes in 117ms
03-15 11:37:40.761: D/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl43820.tmp
03-15 11:37:40.761: W/PackageParser(58): Unknown element under <application>: intent-filter at /data/app/vmdl43820.tmp Binary XML file line #33
03-15 11:37:40.852: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1647 objects / 85064 bytes in 71ms
03-15 11:37:40.852: I/dalvikvm-heap(58): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.995MB for 16400-byte allocation
03-15 11:37:40.931: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 168 objects / 8904 bytes in 72ms
03-15 11:37:41.091: I/PackageManager(58): Removing non-system package:com.example.yayaa
03-15 11:37:41.091: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.example.yayaa uid=10040
03-15 11:37:41.211: D/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.example.yayaa
03-15 11:37:41.211: I/PackageManager(58): Package com.example.yayaa codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.yayaa-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
03-15 11:37:41.221: I/PackageManager(58): /data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk changed; unpacking
03-15 11:37:41.232: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk' ---
03-15 11:37:41.642: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.652: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.652: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.652: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.652: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.671: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.682: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.682: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:41.682: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
03-15 11:37:42.072: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.072: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.081: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
03-15 11:37:42.081: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.091: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.091: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.091: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.091: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.243: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.243: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.243: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.251: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.251: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.261: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
03-15 11:37:42.282: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.282: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.282: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.282: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
03-15 11:37:42.291: I/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
03-15 11:37:42.362: D/dalvikvm(299): DexOpt: load 159ms, verify 638ms, opt 26ms
03-15 11:37:42.392: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk' (success) ---
03-15 11:37:42.392: W/PackageManager(58): Code path for pkg : com.example.yayaa changing from /data/app/com.example.yayaa-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk
03-15 11:37:42.402: W/PackageManager(58): Resource path for pkg : com.example.yayaa changing from /data/app/com.example.yayaa-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk
03-15 11:37:42.402: D/PackageManager(58):   Services: com.example.yayaa.babaa
03-15 11:37:42.402: D/PackageManager(58):   Receivers: com.example.yayaa.ByReceiver
03-15 11:37:42.411: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.example.yayaa uid=10040
03-15 11:37:42.522: I/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.yayaa-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.yayaa-1.apk@classes.dex
03-15 11:37:42.532: D/PackageManager(58): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.yayaa-1.apk
03-15 11:37:42.532: W/PackageManager(58): Unknown permission android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT in package com.example.yayaa
03-15 11:37:42.652: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.example.yayaa uid=10040
03-15 11:37:42.751: I/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=300 uid=10010 gids={}
03-15 11:37:42.841: W/RecognitionManagerService(58): no available voice recognition services found
03-15 11:37:43.032: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5455 objects / 375128 bytes in 180ms
03-15 11:37:43.182: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 618 objects / 32776 bytes in 150ms
03-15 11:37:43.182: I/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.yayaa-2.apk@classes.dex
03-15 11:37:43.201: D/AndroidRuntime(284): Shutting down VM
03-15 11:37:43.243: D/dalvikvm(284): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-15 11:37:43.312: I/ActivityThread(300): Publishing provider com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
03-15 11:37:43.862: D/dalvikvm(152): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3958 objects / 239232 bytes in 59ms
03-15 11:37:48.602: D/dalvikvm(246): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1948 objects / 141368 bytes in 126ms
03-15 11:37:51.301: D/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
03-15 11:37:51.541: D/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
03-15 11:37:53.581: D/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
03-15 11:37:53.951: D/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
03-15 11:37:54.111: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x34ba58:0x34bc20] in 1018044 ns
03-15 11:39:30.771: I/CheckinService(169): Preparing to send checkin request
03-15 11:39:30.771: I/EventLogService(169): Accumulating logs since 1363327374579
03-15 11:39:30.891: V/CheckinRequestBuilder(169): pre-froyo android id is 0
03-15 11:39:31.052: I/CheckinTask(169): Sending checkin request (1372 bytes)
03-15 11:39:32.141: E/CheckinTask(169): SSL error, attempting time correction: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
03-15 11:39:32.632: I/CheckinTask(169): Server time agrees: delta 389 msec
03-15 11:39:32.702: D/NativeCrypto(169): Freeing OpenSSL session
03-15 11:39:32.702: D/dalvikvm(169): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4789 objects / 513296 bytes in 61ms
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:199)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:256)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient$WrappedLayeredSocketFactory.createSocket(GoogleHttpClient.java:160)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:248)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(GoogleHttpClient.java:203)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:245)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:313)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinTask.sendRequest(CheckinTask.java:239)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinTask.doInBackground(CheckinTask.java:146)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService$1.doInBackground(CheckinService.java:221)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService$1.doInBackground(CheckinService.java:228)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:168)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     ... 24 more
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:149)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:202)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:164)
03-15 11:39:32.722: E/CheckinTask(169):     ... 25 more
03-15 11:40:55.501: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 1):

when looking at a logcat exception stack trace the reason is often in the 'caused by:' field.

here, its caused by :

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found
```

you may need to set a custom trust manager to your http request, as shown in this really good post :

[Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872)

Comment: Trusting all certificates is a great security risk though.

Comment: Yes, my advise was to implement a custom trust manager  based on the linked example. Not to trust all without anymore reflexion.